# How to collect form data in multiple steps and summarize it

Tags: javascript

**Problem**

I have a form which is divided into five different sections. *Find the Image below*. When a person comes on this page I direct him/her directly to the **Summary stage** with pre-populated data which is working fine. Where the problem comes is there's an option for the user to go n edit this form by clicking on **prev** button. After the user changes the value in the previous stages and comes back to the summary stage it still shows them the default information which came through the pre-populated data but when a user submit form it submits the correct info with new edited data.

Is there any way I can refresh or reload it? I'm using the below code to display this summary.

**Code**

```
//Button to reach the summary stage    
<button type="button" class="next" id="summary" onclick="loadnext(4,5);"><img src="images/next.jpg" alt="" /> </button>


//Display
<tr>
    <td>Team Name</td>
    <td id='t_name_SUM'></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Team Visibility</td>
    <td id='t_visibility_SUM'></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: You need to work with multi-page forms. http://www.html-form-guide.com/php-form/php-order-form.html

Comment: You're already using jQuery, you don't need to use `document.getElementById` or `innerHTML`, you can simply `$('#myId').html()`. Check out http://try.jquery.com for an interactive tutorial! :)

Comment: You mean you want to wipe out the following steps if the input in one step is changed? That shouldn't be too hard.

Comment: @Bergi I don't want to wipe out anything. I just want to change the summary which is coming through with updated data. E.g: if pre-populated data says team name = "My team" and user goes back and change it to "Joes Team11" then on summary it should display team name = "Joes Team11" whereas even after the change made by the user it shows team name = "My team"

Comment: You are probably not storing all the settings in some global object. If you're copying HTML into the summaries it's a recipe for disaster. You should be able to **generate the summary** not copying the HTML.

Comment: @Bart I'm new to JS. Can u give me an example. tnx

Comment: According the code, this should work. I suggest you start firebug (or similar tool), set a breakpoint on the second if (on the scripts panel you can debug any running scripts), and proceed step-by-step to identify the problem. Maybe a getElementById is returning null, and so it breaks the execution.

Answer (score 2):

*To better support my comment I'm writing this answer.*

What you need to do is provide a mechanism to collect data step by step. Copying HTML into other elements is not a very flexible way to do that.

I created a [jsfiddle to demonstrate the idea](http://jsfiddle.net/7uUpy/). It's far from perfect but at this stage it works without making things to complicated.

The basic idea is to have an object to control the flow of the views(steps) the user needs to handle. Each view has a controller associated with it to handle the data.

The views.

```
<div id="step1" class="view">
    <h3>Step #1</h3>
    <input type="text" name="name" value="" />
</div>

<div id="step2" class="view">
    <h3>Step #2</h3>
    <input type="text" name="title" value="" />
</div>

<div id="step3" class="view">
    <h3>Step #3</h3>
    <input type="text" name="message" value="" />
</div>
```

The object controlling the flow (only showing the most relevant parts).

```
var flow = {
    ...
    settings:{}, // settings to save
    routes: [
        {controller:Step1Ctrl, element:'#step1'},
        {controller:Step2Ctrl, element:'#step2'},
        {controller:Step3Ctrl, element:'#step3'} 
    ],

    ...

    show: function (index) {
        var route = this.routes[index];

        if (this.currentController) {
            this.currentController.commit();
        }

        this.index = index;
        this.currentController = new route.controller(
            this.settings, 
            route.element
        );
    }
};
```

Every time a new view is shown the current controller commits the changes to `settings` and a new controller is created for the current view.

A simple controller can look like this.

```
function Step1Ctrl(settings, element) {

    var $e = $(element).find('input[name="name"]');
    $e.val(settings.name);  //set the initial value

    this.commit = function () {
        settings.name = $e.val(); //save
    };
}
```

Since every controller now commits it's changes to `settings` it easy to represent that data in any way you like. The fiddle just alerted the collected data but you can easily create another view and another controller to display thse settings.

Also, because every controller has access to the settings it can act upon values that are already in there or check if a combination of settings is even possible or not.